# F# unit of measure to model area

Tags: f#

How can I use F# unit of measure to model the area of certain geometries.

The code i have so far is this but it isn't quite compiling.

```ml
[<Measure>] type radius
[<Measure>] type PI
[<Measure>] type area

let convertRadiusToArea (r:float<radius>) : float<area>  =
    // let pi = System.Math.PI
    let a:float<PI> = 3.14<PI>
    r * r * System.Math.PI
```

Comment: „it isn‘t quite compiling” is not a helpful statement. Please include at least the compiler error (as text, not screenshot). This is especially important for e.g. other users facing the same problem or finding existing solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better example of using F#'s unit of measure would be this:

```
[<Measure>] type cm

let convertRadiusToArea(r:float<cm>) : float<cm^2> =
    r * r * System.Math.PI
```

The idea being that you get benefits of the units of measurement in your calculations and derivations. You're not getting that by creating a unit of measure called 'radius'. Is it in meters? Feet? Centimetres? And that is why you would introduce them into an F# function, to be non-ambiguous about the unit of measurement for the inputs and outputs.

Units of measure in F# should IMO be modelled the way we use units of measurement in any other calculations or real world example like speed, temperature, force etc.

Comment: Or even better, use standard units `FSharp.Data.UnitSystems.SI.` `UnitSymbols` or `UnitNames`

Answer (score 3):

There are several things here:

1. You need to define area as being a square length with `type area = radius * radius`. Otherwise the compiler has no way to match your input and output units.
2. Pi, when used like this, is dimensionless, which is represented in F# as `<1>` or just no unit suffix.

```
[<Measure>] type radius
[<Measure>] type area = radius * radius

let convertRadiusToArea (r:float<radius>) : float<area>  =
    let pi = System.Math.PI
    r * r * pi
```